# Mocha testing express.js app http request

Tags: testing, express, mocha.js

I need to test a right response that comes from route function.

In https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/app.router.js 
I see code:

```
app.get('/:name', function(req, res, next){
  res.send(req.params.name);
});

request(app)
.get('/foo%2Fbar')
.expect('foo/bar', done);
```

I wonder what is **request(app)** how can I include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the top of that file you will see:

```
 request = require('./support/http')
```

Go to the ./support/http file:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/support/http.js

Here you can see the following:

```
 module.exports = require('supertest');
```

Now that you know the name of the module you can search the npm (node package manager) database:

http://packagefinder1-enome.dotcloud.com/search?q=supertest

If you want to use this module you need to install it with:

```
 npm install supertest
```